# testing matplotlib 3D plots using pytest

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytest

I was wondering is it possible for py test to assert a 3D plot output using pytest, for instance if i have a parametric function accepting user inputs:

```
def 3D_plot(a=4,b=100,c=2,d=1):

    import matplotlib as mpl
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    pl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    theta = np.linspace(-a * np.pi, a * np.pi, b)
    z = np.linspace(-c, c, b)
    r = z**c + d
    x = r * np.sin(theta)
    y = r * np.cos(theta)
    ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
    ax.legend()

    plt.show()
```

I wish to write an @pytest.mark.parametrize() test for it, using pytest.

Sincerely

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? It seems you can just use it as it is, or is there any problem with it?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of a regression test? You could save the figure to an image and compare the file against a prepared reference image. However, such tests are usually pretty fragile, requiring to update the reference files from time to time.

Comment: I have two .py files one is code and other is test. The code generates the plot and the test code also generates the plot (both on the fly for a list of list containing values for a,b,c,d). SO i want to assert that the respective plots created by my code are similar to that by code.

Comment: But then the test and the code to test are just the same and you don't need any test?

Comment: In the code file I just run it for single values of a,b,c,d respectively. But I was interested in testing by simulating it over entire range of possible inputs, using the test file with the help of a generator function.

Comment: Again, what do you want to test? If your code file and test are the same, you don't need any test, as same code creates same output. If they are not the same, what exactly is the property that should be tested?

Comment: apologies for being inexpressive. Lets assume input a ranges from (0.000 to 1.000) similarly b,c,d have there respective input range. Now how would I know if my code runs for all possible combinations.

Comment: By "runs correctly" you mean it does not produce an error? That would be exactly done with the code you have and something like `@pytest.mark.parametrize('a,b,c,d', listofparameterlists)`. Possibly, calling `fig.canvas.draw()` instead of `plt.show()` is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks man let me try it I will get back if it doesn't